# How do I optimize this Linq query to find blog posts with the most views in past 24 hours

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a blog website which regularly retrieves the view count for each blog post from Google Analytics and stores it in the database. The Blog table has a one to many relationship with the ViewStats table. The ViewStats table simple stores Date and Views.

The 2 relevant tables are as follows:

```
|   Blog   |   ViewStats  |
-----------+--------------|
|   Id     |   Id         |
|   Title  |   Date       |
|   Body   |   Views      |
|          |   BlogId     |
```

It is an MVC website using Entity Framework with Repositories set up in a Data Access layer.

What I want to do is get the 3 blog posts with the most views in the past 24 hours. All the views stored in the DB are cumulative and so I need to order by the most recent result minus the last result from 24 hours ago for each blog post.

Example of the data:

```
|   Id    |            Date              |   Views   |   BlogId   |    
----------+------------------------------+-----------+------------|
|    1    |   2014-10-01 16:05:37.573    |    10     |     1      |
|    2    |   2014-10-01 16:05:37.573    |     8     |     2      |
|    3    |   2014-10-01 16:10:40.333    |    32     |     1      |
|    4    |   2014-10-01 16:10:40.333    |    12     |     2      |
```

This is the query I have:

```
var query = blogRepo.GetBlogs()
    .OrderByDescending(a => 
        (a.ViewStats.OrderByDescending(v => v.Date)
            .Select(v => v.Views)
            .FirstOrDefault())
        - (a.ViewStats.Where(v => v.Date < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
            .OrderByDescending(v => v.Date)
            .Select(v => v.Views)
            .FirstOrDefault()))
    .Take(3);
```

However, it runs incredibly slowly now having about 10,000 rows in the ViewStats table. Does anyone know a more efficient way of achieving this result?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't any (or all) of that be done in sql?

Comment: @Jerrington If the OP is using EF, then the Linq query will be translated to SQL.

Comment: Have you considered doing a simple GROUP BY? And check your indices.

Comment: You could probably speed this up by changing the where clauses so there's less data to sort on.  I.e. put a where on the most recent so that it only gets records in the database that have occurred in the past 15 minutes.  You could also swap the where and order by on the one from 24 hours ago by doing something like where Date > Date - 1 day and do an ascending sort rather than a descending sort.

Comment: Make sure you are querying against an `IQueryable` and not an `IEnumerable`. I'm looking at `GetBlogs()` specifically.

Comment: @cgotberg Sounded good, but I'm afraid it hasn't made it any quicker.

Comment: @Shoe It was IEnumerable, but changing it to an IQueryable I get the error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @Shoe Nevermind, worked out a way to do it just by creating a DateTime variable yesterday and using that within the query. A lot quicker now. Thank you everyone for suggestions.

Comment: See my answer on why it was slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments your `blogRepo.GetBlogs()` is returning an IEnumerable which is forcing the query to be performed in memory rather than being translated into SQL and running against the DB. This is why it's slow.

Make `GetBlogs()` return an `IQueryable` to take advantage of database speed.

Comment: Thanks. The change to IQueryable was the solution. However, to keep the repository only returning IEnumerable, my senior developer recommended putting the method into GetPopularBlogs(int numOfResults) in the repository. Many thanks.

Comment: Good to hear, though you should need only one because you can use `AsQueryable` and `AsEnumerable` to go back and forth between the two interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you correctly map navigation collection property in your classes.
Also make sure your GetBlogs method returns IQueryable.

```
// var blogs = blogRepo.GetBlogs();
var start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
var best =
    from blog in blogs
    let total = blog.Stats.Where(s => s.Date > start).Sum(i => i.Views)
    orderby total descending
    select new
    {
        blog, total
    };

var results = best.Take(3);
```

Working example here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/9C0p8c